# OCR of a pdf with gocr

Tags: 20.04, ocr

I installed gocr, with the command suggested by the ubuntu terminal (sudo apt install gocr), in order to carry out an OCR recognition of the text in a pdf file.
How could I use it? I didn't find a tutorial to do this.

Answer (score 4):

On newer Ubuntu versions it was replaced with **tesseract-ocr**: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/tesseract-ocr/

For simple usage with a GUI, I recommend using **gImageReader**:
https://github.com/manisandro/gImageReader/releases

installation:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sandromani/gimagereader
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimagereader tesseract-ocr tesseract-ocr-eng
```

Comment: via ppa see here: https://www.fosslinux.com/27198/gimagereader-an-open-source-pdf-app-with-ocr-capability.htm

Comment: Please add some instructions for installation instead of just posting links

Comment: very useful , I've  Installed also a secondary language (italian) with sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr-ita